# Youtube Data API is getting called too many times

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I set up the youtube data api and I added following code to fetch 4 videos on my page: Works fine for like 3 hours before the daily quota of 10.000 is reached. I tested it locally and everything worked fine there. Also: I´m using the search resource and its list method, which result in a quota cost of 100 per call, but that normally shouldnt be a problem, because its a small page.Thx in advance.

```js
const youtubeWrapper = document.querySelector(".youtube-playlist");
async function getFloVideoData(){
    const response = await fetch("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC78M9ne3s4_XpcmPM4r0Xxw&maxResults=4&order=viewCount&key=myAPIkey");
    const data = await response.json();
    const {items} = data;

    items.forEach((item) => {
      youtubeWrapper.innerHTML += `<div class="video-container"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${item.id.videoId}"><img src="${item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}"></a><p>${item.snippet.title}</p><p>${item.snippet.publishTime}</p></div>`;
    });

 )
}
setTimeout(getFloVideoData(),3600000); //call function every hour too limit API-Calls
```

Comment: Would be possible your api key is used by someone else? - does your api key is restricted? how do you know it is called too may times? - please [edit] your question with your findings

Comment: Are you using the API to list videos on another web page? Like a website of yours? If so, what is your daily traffic?